# How can I remove quotation marks before a .Sort in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, sorting, string-comparison

I'm trying to sort items out alphabetically and sort place them into a new textbox. I've got everything down except for trying to make exceptions for quotation marks, as they appear before letters do. So far I have

`Dim holder as List(Of Strings) = New List(Of String)'holds my values
Dim input as List(Of RichTextBox) = New List(Of RichTextBox)'where text is input`

```
For i As Integer = 0 to input.Count - 1
   holder.Add(input.ElementAt(i))
Next
  holder.Sort()
For i As Integer = 0 to holder.Count - 1
   txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + vbCrLf + holder(i)
Next
```

How do I ignore quotation marks that may be entered? I also need to output the information into a textbox sorted, but with the quotation marks back in the strings that were sorted.

Comment: `Holder = Holder.Select(Function(s) s.Replace("""", "")).ToList()`

Comment: I'm very new to programming and this is my first independent project, where would I put that line?

Comment: If they all have them they wont interfere with the sorting.  otherwise if you want to `remove quotation marks before a .Sort` add it before the sort

Answer (score 3):

Just implement your own **[comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** and use the **[List.Sort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** method overload that takes a custom comparer.

A short example:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MyComparer : Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Compare(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As String) As Integer _
    Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare

        a = a.Trim({"'"c, ControlChars.Quote})
        b = b.Trim({"'"c, ControlChars.Quote})

        Return New CaseInsensitiveComparer().Compare(a, b)

    End Function

End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String) From {"'b'", "''''a'", """d""", "c"}
list.Sort(New MyComparer)
```

Comment: Just because I'm a learning student, would you mind going through and explaining the process here?

Comment: `IComparer` is an interface that "teaches" .NET how to test 2 objects to see how they compare with each other. Comparing objects is the key part of sorting lists, so you can use a custom `ICompare` implementation to sort a list in almost any way you can think of.  Basically, his comparer takes the 2 strings to compare and temporarily removes the quotation marks and then compares those results to each other.  It's a **great** example of using IComparer, but keep in mind that it will have some serious performance issues when sorting very large lists because it constantly creates new strings.